# Can dupes moving horizontially move faster if there is a square between the firepole and the ladder?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

[Firepoles](https://oxygennotincluded.gamepedia.com/Fire_Pole) and ladders are often paired in many base designs because firepoles are cheap and fast, and any firepole usually needs a ladder for regular upward speed.

Some dupes, however, will not be moving down or up but across the area where the pole and ladder are placed.  The faster dupes can get around the more they can accomplish in a day. So it makes me wonder if the dupes are faster horizontally when jumping straight from tile to pole to ladder to tile, or if they are faster with a square in between the tile and pole (tile/pole/tile/ladder/tile).  That way the dupe could just execute two jumps instead of mounting the firepole and the ladder.  But maybe they mount the ladder and firepole regardless?

[image: Firepole]

What's the optimal design for a high horizontal traffic firepole area?

Comment: Won't they always have that option, even with an extra tile? You could build it and time how fast the dupes run.

Comment: @MrFox - I added an answer that links to my post of the same question on the official forum.  Hopefully that answers your question, or at least the link to the answer will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked [this question on the official Oxygen not included forum](https://forums.kleientertainment.com/forums/topic/94334-can-dupes-moving-horizontially-move-faster-if-there-is-a-square-between-the-firepole-and-the-ladder/?tab=comments) and I got an answer that was so complex that its hard to boil down into an easy to understand nugget of information.

Here's what I think is the main snippet of that answer:

> 1. Tiles are the fastest(obviously). Substituting with metal tiles will give you even faster run speed.
> 2. cut ladders/poles are as fast as tiles(excluding the 25% run speed bonus)(~80% tile speed)*
> 3. distant ladders/poles - same speed regardless if distant cut/uncut(so better use uncut)(~60% tile speed)
>          a bit slower than cut ladders/poles
>          a lot faster than ladders/poles**
> 4. ladders/poles are the slowest!(33.3% tile speed)***